# How to include -lm in Makefile.am or configure.ac

Tags: c, makefile, autotools

I have a program called `neuromz` that I compile using

```
gcc neuromz.c -lm -o neuromz
```

It's work fine but if I try to add to my project a `configure.ac` and `Makefile.am`, with `Makefile.am`:

```
bin_PROGRAMS = neuromz
neuromz_SOURCES = neuromz.c neuromz.h ann.c ann.h 
neuromz_CFLAGS = -lm
```

the result is:

```
/home/mz/programming/ctest/ANN/ann.c:11: undefined reference to `exp'
/home/mz/programming/ctest/ANN/ann.c:11: undefined reference to `exp'
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @MikeKinghan already described, the Automake variables for specifying extra libraries into a program are `*_LDADD`.  I'll add, however, that if you're only building one program, or if all of the programs you're building need the same libraries, then you can use `LDADD` instead.  This can be more convenient, and it sometimes produces smaller `Makefile`'s, too:

```
bin_PROGRAMS = neuromz
LDADD = -lm

neuromz_SOURCES = neuromz.c neuromz.h ann.c ann.h
```

HOWEVER, if you're satisfied to make a once-for-all decision about `libm` for the programs built by your build system, then I'd recommend handling it in Autoconf instead of Automake.  If you put this in your `configure.ac` ...

```
AC_SEARCH_LIBS([sqrt], [m])
```

... then

- Your `configure` script will check whether `libm` needs to be explicitly linked at all (which depends on your environment and tool chain), and will add `-lm` only if necessary.
- You don't then need to say anything about it in your `Makefile.am`, nor be concerned with which Automake variable to use.

Answer (score 4):

Your commandline:

```
gcc neuromz.c -lm -o neuromz
```

is shorthand that gcc helpfully translates into the necessary compile step and
link step, as if you did:

```
gcc -c -o neuromz.o neuromz.c   # Compile
gcc -o neuromz neuromz.o -lm    # Link
```

Automake always separates compilation and linkage, because that typically makes
builds as economical as they can be.

```
neuromz_CFLAGS = -lm
```

adds `-lm` to the compiler options (`CFLAGS`) for compiling `neuromz.c`.
But `-lm` ( = *link the math library*) is a linkage option and ignored in compilation. You need it
in the linkage options (`LDADD`):

```
neuromz_LDADD = -lm
```

See the [automake manual 8.4 Program and Library Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Program-and-Library-Variables.html)